# Independent and identically distributed data (images)?

Tags: image-processing, iid

If it is said that the data must be independent and identically distributed, and the data are images, then what exactly does it mean for images to be "independent and identically distributed"?

Comment: It depends on the model: what data-generation model are you assuming?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, where do your images come from, and how are they represented as data? Data do not always have to be i.i.d., only if you want to do something that requires this. Some methods require i.i.d. not of the data themselves but rather of "residuals" or "innovations", which are derived from the data in formal ways.  Also, it's a formal assumption within a formal model, never literally fulfilled in reality, and to what extent it is a reasonable assumption for your data depends on the details for which I ask.

Comment: @whuber This was made as a *general* statement for image data (to then be used for machine learning image classification). So it could be face images for facial recognition, geospatial images, etc.

Comment: @Lewian As I said in my comment above, this was given as a *general* statement about image data – so I'm assuming you can select any specific context you like. Since it is a general statement about image data, I am therefore asking the general question of what it means for images to be "independent and identically distributed"?

Comment: How do you conceive of this question as being special to images, which in a statistical setting are naturally conceived of as vector-valued random variables, for which the standard definitions of "identical" and "independent" distributions automatically apply?

Comment: @whuber I *don't* – you seem to be misunderstanding me. I'm asking about this in terms of the representation of images as images themselves – not of the representation of images as data. So what does it mean for *any* set of images – it could be facial images, body images, geospatial images, tree images, building images, astronomical images, ect. – to be independent and identically distributed. What characteristics do these images have to have?

Comment: Huh?  What distinction are you making between an image -- which I believe we all understand as being arrays of numbers -- and "data"?  Indeed, what can you possibly mean by "distributed" unless you are talking about quantities that can have a distribution in the first place, and how could such quantities possibly not be data?

Comment: @whuber Take the example of facial recognition images in China. I don't know what "independent" would mean in this context, but I think "identically distributed" would mean that the faces of the people would have to all be Chinese (that is, of the facial structure variation you'd see from populations living in China). If you then throw in facial images of people from Africa, it seems to me that this would mean that the images are no longer identically distributed, right? Do you see what I mean?

Comment: That's not right.  If you conceive of a huge repository of images -- *any* images -- and you sample from that repository with replacement, you will have a model of iid images.  Whether they come from China or Africa doesn't matter and plays no role in this statistical concept.

Comment: @whuber So if the "huge repository" consists of 1.5 billion Chinese faces, and then we add in a handful of African faces, this, according to you, does not decrease the extent to which the dataset is identically distributed?

Comment: @whuber Another example: What if we take a dataset of great white shark images, and then add in a handful of blue whale images. Are you telling me that this doesn't decrease the extent to which the data are identically distributed?

Comment: The distribution is determined by (a) the contents of the box and (b) the sampling method.  When two images are sampled with the same process, in such a way that the result of sampling one does not change the properties of that process (which is why you must replace the image after sampling it!), then any random variable defined on the space of those images is IID.  There isn't any part of the standard statistical definition that refers to sharks and whales :-). Now, if you sample from one box and then change its contents and sample again, the RVs probably are differently distributed.

Comment: @whuber See (1) of Lewian's answer: The African faces are not drawn from the same population as the Chinese images. Is this not what I'm referring to?

Comment: If you are drawing images from two different probability spaces, then it's unlikely that random variables defined on those spaces will have the same distributions (although they can), so I don't get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the general meaning of i.i.d. and apply it to images. I.i.d. then means that

(1) images are drawn randomly from the same population of images (this is for example violated if you have access to a number of databases and you decide to draw the same number of images from each, or, even worse, you take 10000 images from your favourite database and 10 from each of the others),

(2) once some images are drawn, these do not contain any information about other images to be drawn, other than information about the general population (this is for example violated if the population you're interested in is general images, let's say all on the web, but you find out from seeing the first 100 images that almost all your images actually show animals).

Note that whether data are i.i.d. to some extent depends on the population you want to make inference about. If your population is all images in one database, and you draw randomly from that database only, this can be taken as i.i.d. However it is not i.i.d. if in fact your population of interest is all images on the web, because then the specific database may not be representative (for example because it has very many animal images) and the fact that all images come from the same database makes them dependent. The difference is that in one case the fact that there are many animal pictures is a feature of the population of interest, and given this the images are independent. In the other case the fact that there are many animal pictures is not a feature of the population, but a result of all your images being from the same database, which makes then dependent relative to the more general population.

PS: Somebody could argue that (1) above implies (2), because if there's dependence as suggested in (2), it actually means that you didn't sample truly randomly from the same population. This objection is true if "random draw" is interpreted accordingly, however I think it's useful to make this distinction to make clearer how identity and independence can go wrong in different ways.

PPS: Note that "i.i.d." is *not* a property of the images per se, but rather of your way of drawing them from a well-defined population.

Comment: Doesn't (1) support my example (see comment) of Chinese facial recognition (Chinese facial population) and African facial images then being added in? Isn't that what my example illustrates? The African faces are not drawn from the same population as the Chinese faces.

Comment: As I wrote, it depends on the population. If you have a database with some Chinese and some African facial images, and that's your population of interest, it can still be i.i.d. if you sample properly at random (I think this is what whuber means). If your population is all images on the web, and for some reason you only draw Chinese and African facial images, it's not i.i.d. Also if you *systematically* first draw Chinese then African, it's not i.i.d.

Comment: Note also my PPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the images as realizations of matrix or tensor random variables, even regular vector random variables if you flatten each image to a vector, the same way that we think of any other observations as realizations of random variables. So before we have realizations of the random variables, we just have the random variables.

Once we see images as vector random variables, “iid” means the same as always. Yes, there are relationships between the pixels of an individual image, same as there are relationships between the components of a multivariate normal distribution with a non-diagonal covariance matrix. The “independent” and “identical” means across observations, not within.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, the point you're making is that it doesn't necessarily mean that the images are i.i.d. between their own individual pixels, but rather that they are i.i.d. between the individual images themselves?

Comment: Exactly, same as in any other multivariate distribution.

Comment: What would be an applied/practical example of this?